# Confusion in integrating socialize SDK in an App?

Tags: java, android, sdk, comments, socialize-sdk

I'm new at coding and trying to integrate Socialize SDK with my app but failing to do so please help.

Documentation of the socialize tells me to add the following after adding the SDK module.

**1)** add code to AndroidManifest.xml but after adding SDK I got Two AndroidManifest files; one within my app and one in SDK.
[I added code in manifest file of app and got the errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gFYu.png)

so in which manifest file I have to add the code?

**2)** tells me to add the following code and I got these errors

[Why everything turned red, can anybody please tell what I'm doing wrong.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0VrA.png)

Later I also tried to add manifest code (mentioned in 1st point) in SDK manifest but I still got errors mentioned in the second point.

Please Help.